# Breakpoint in a static lib doesn't work if the function is called indirectly

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I'm developing an application that uses Qt5, CMake for build, and QtCreator as IDE.

The project consists of a **SDK** static library, a **core** shared library that uses functions from **SDK** library, and two **gui** application that uses the **core** library functions and some functions of **SDK** library directly.

If I debug the **gui** application with a breakpoint inside a **SDK** library function:

- if the function is called by **core** library, the debugger doesn't break
- if the function is called directly by **gui** application, the debugger breaks on it.

Why? I think that I'm wronging something in the CMake configuration

The structure of my project is the following:

```
MyProject/
├── SDK/
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── MP/
│       └── Utils.h
├── core/
|   ├── CMakeLists.txt
|   ├── core_global.h
│   ├── Core.h
│   └── Core.cpp
├── desktop-gui/
|   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
├── mobile-gui/
|   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
```

Below are the CMakeLists files:

`MyProject/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(MyProject LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(SDK)
add_subdirectory(core)
add_subdirectory(desktop-gui)
```

`SDK/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(sdk LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
  MP/Utils.h
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/MP")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core)
```

`core/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(core LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)

add_library(core SHARED
  core_global.h
  Core.cpp
  Core.h
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        Qt5::Core
    PUBLIC
        sdk
)
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC CORE_LIBRARY)
```

`desktop-gui/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(desktop-gui LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
  main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(Application
    Qt5::Core
    sdk
    core
)
```

A short example. My **SDK** library has a function

```cpp
namespace MP {
    class Utils
    {
    public:
        static int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
    };
}
```

My **core** library has a function

```cpp
class Core
{
public:
    int doAnOperation(int a, int b) 
    { 
        return MP::Utils::sum(a, b); 
    }
};
```

My **gui** application

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Core core;
    std::cout << core.doAnOperation(2, 2); // Don't stop on breakpoint
    std::cout << MP::Utils::sum(2, 2); // Stops on breakpoint

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your compiler isn't inlining the definitions of that very small function? Inspect the generated code.

Comment: In my real application, the function that I call consists of 4 for loops and 1 while loop and I'm assuming that the compiler doesn't inline this kind of function. By the way, I don't know how I can inspect the generated code. Can you suggest to me how?

Comment: `objdump -d` (Linux) or `otool -tV` (macOS). Search for the calling code and see if there is a call to the function or if it was replaced by a giant blob of code.

Comment: Thanks! I've checked with *dumpbin* on win and I found the call to the function. 5 rows after `?doAnOperation@Core@@QEAAHHH@Z:` there is `call @ILT+465(?sum@Utils@MP@@SAHHH@Z)`

Comment: MP::SDK::sum is not the same as MP::Utils::Sum, unless you changed that (for some reason) for posting here.

Comment: Thats right! I edited the previous comment. Sorry but I'm working on an example that it's a bit different wrt the simple one that I've reported